# Child class of EditText looks different than normal EditText on Android 4

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-custom-view

This is a 'bug' that I discovered while working on a real app, but I created a blank project to reproduce it.

I have the following layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <com.example.test.testapp.MyEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


</LinearLayout>
```

The class `MyEditText`  looks like this:

```
public class MyEditText extends EditText {

    public MyEditText(Context context){
        super(context);
    }

    public MyEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
        super(context, attrs);
    }


    public MyEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle){
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }


}
```

My `styles.xml` file is empty except for the Theme

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>

</resources>
```

I would expect the `MyEditText` to look like the normal `EditText` and it does on Android 5.0, but not on Android 2.3.7, Android 4.1.3 or Android 4.4.4.

On those Android versions the `EditText`s differ in color, the normal one has a cyan underline when focused, the custom one has a black underline:

[image]

[image]

Why is this happening and how can I prevent it?

**EDIT / UPDATE:**

Google [seems to have adressed this](http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2015/04/android-support-library-221.html) in the support library by introducing, amongst others, an AppCompatEditText class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why is this happening

Because you are using AppCompat. Quoting [the blog post on the subject](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html):

> Q: Why is my EditText (or other widget listed above) not being tinted correctly on my pre-Lollipop device?
>
> A: The widget tinting in AppCompat works by intercepting any layout inflation and inserting a special tint-aware version of the widget in its place. For most people this will work fine, but I can think of a few scenarios where this won’t work, including:
>
> - You have your own custom version of the widget (i.e. you’ve extended EditText)
> - You are creating the EditText without a LayoutInflater (i.e., calling new EditText()).

So, the behavior is expected. The AppCompat backport provides some lightweight backporting of tinting, but it's not going to handle all cases.

> how can I prevent it?

Off the cuff, either:

- Do not create a subclass of `EditText`, or
- When running on AppCompat, look up the tint and figure out how to apply it yourself, perhaps by examining the AppCompat source code (assuming it's available -- I haven't looked for it), or
- Do not use AppCompat, and see if tinting works as expected using `Theme.Material` on Android 5.0+ devices

It's possible that a future AppCompat could provide some sort of system for subclasses to participate in the tinting process. And there may be other solutions than these -- these are what come to mind.

Comment: Wow, did you have this answer already prepared? :) Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @Ascorbin: "Wow, did you have this answer already prepared?" -- well, it's half a quote, which saves on typing. :-) I'll need to look at my second option myself at some point, as I have [a subclass of `EditText`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-richedit) that will suffer from the same problem.

Answer (score 5):

Actually the conclusion reached in this accepted answer here is not entirely true (anymore). You **SHOULD** use AppCompat, but just need to realise that AppCompat will substitute your EditText with AppCompatEditText during layout inflation. The same process happens to a few other UI elements too, like Switch, CheckBoxes, etc. Google did this so that they can push Material design look-n-feel as far and wide with minimal code changes from the users.

If you want to subclass EditText, you should subclass AppCompatEditText (`android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText`).