# Android Button background color not changing

Tags: android, xml, material-components-android

In this android project im creating a default button style.
my styles.xml

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/ButtonStlye123</item>
</style>

<style name="ButtonStlye123" parent="android:style/Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:textSize">19dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_margin">8dp</item>
    <item name="android:padding">8dp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/ColorDivider</item>

    <item name="android:background">@color/ColorAccent</item>
</style>
```

my button in a fragment.

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/btnLogin"
    android:id="@+id/btn_login"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:theme="@style/ButtonStlye123"
    android:onClick="login" />
```

In the preview in android studio it looks exactly like I want, but when I run the app on my device the background color is gray ("default button color"). If i change the text color in my styles.xml like:

```
<item name="android:textColor">@color/ColorPrimary</item>
```

it changes (also on my device) so the custom style is loading, i tryd different colors (that worked for the text) for the button but it wont change.

Why isnt my background color loading?

Comment: are you sure the style name "buttonstyle123" and in your button "questbuttonstyle" shouldn't be the same?

Comment: @alltooconfusingthereforesleep yes they should, typo when placing it here. they are the same in my app

Comment: TRY: android:style="@style/ButtonStlye123" (instead of "theme")

Comment: Styles are for components, and Themes are for App (or global attributes).  They are different in concept (not sure if they are different in execution)

Comment: change backgroundTint

Comment: @Booger please check whether it is android:style attribute or simple 'style="@style/ButtonStlye123"' only.

Comment: Material theme overrides your background tint, you can use `app:backgroundTint="@null"` or remove MaterialTheme

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think you need to change your attribute from "theme" to "style".  These files are intended for different things, so are used differently.

Style is used to assign attributes to individual views or components, and Theme is used to apply attributes to the entire app.

So try this instead:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/btnLogin"
    android:id="@+id/btn_login"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    <!-- This attribute was changed -->        
    android:style="@style/ButtonStlye123"
    android:onClick="login" />
```

You should also split these different types of XML into the correct files as appropriate (styles.xml and themes.xml - instead of keeping them all in the same file).  This is convention, and won't effect the code compilation or execution, but is recommended as a code style.

Comment: Is it possible to apply to all buttons automaticly?

Comment: If you want to apply a style universally, you would need to create a Java class (of your own custom making), that extends the Button class, and then assign the style in that Java class.  Otherwise, there is no built-in way to make a certain style apply universally.  You CAN put a lot of attributes in the style (including width, height, etc) so this IS way to centalize this stuff (again, you will need to put that _style_ attribute in XML manually (no way to do this automatically)

Comment: im trying this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2410836/how-do-i-apply-a-style-to-all-buttons-of-an-android-application solution but i cant get it to work

Comment: I have never used this.  I think it is easy enough to just apply the style attribute to each view in XML (don't feel the need to apply that universally).

Answer (score 248):

Try using AppCompactButton instead of

```
<Button>
```

use

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton>
```

that will do the trick

**Update: 01/06/2021**

Found out that the above will not work on earlier Android versions.
For material design Button use

```
<Button app:backgroundTint="@color/green">
```

Comment: Interestingly, for me even settings "android:background" directly on the Button did not work. But it works for AppCompatButton. So I guess, it has something to do with the way AppCompatActivity and simple Activity are styled... Anyway, this solution works for me (with AppCompatActivity).

Comment: It worked. But I don't understand the reason behind this.

Comment: I see this issue is common now. Never knew that changing to `AppCompatButton` would fix it. While this isn't really an answer directed to the original question, it certainly helps us now.

Comment: Seems that for a Button, the primary color defined in the app theme takes precedence over any custom background you want to apply to a Button, but it is not the case for the AppCompatButton. Not sure if this is a bug or a feature of Android

Comment: Follow this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30556804/difference-between-an-appcompat-view-and-a-normal-android-view?answertab=active#tab-top, we know Button should be AppCompatButton automatically, but actually it's not.

Comment: Worked fine, I guess we are moving from button to AppCompatButton gradually

Comment: Materiel design Button code works on material designs as expected.

Comment: I could kiss you.  This was an incredibly frustrating issue to try and google.  This also fixes issue with Studio recommending "drawableStart" instead of "drawableLeft" or whatever as drawableStart doesn't work in a Button

Comment: Although this solves my problem, please look at Hor Chanpheng's answer. It also worked for me

Answer (score 55):

Please Use **androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton** instead of **Button**.

```
  <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/button_id_Login"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/textInnputLayout_editText_id_password"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:text="@string/Login_screen_button_text"
        android:background="@drawable/login_button_style"
        android:textAllCaps="false">
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton>
```

Comment: This one solved my problem...Don't use >Button

Comment: @Maduro alternatively, either stop using material theme, or you can also set `app:backgroundTint="@null"`

Answer (score 49):

You might be using `targetSdkVersion 30` material theme

The solution is change `theme.xml` style

From

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
```

To

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

Comment: This has saved my life. Like 3 days trying to find the issue. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you, but why this is happening ?

Comment: @Web.11 : because the latest version of android studio automatically uses Material theme , so button is applied with those theme components. Another way, you can use androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton instead or change parent theme to Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.

Answer (score 28):

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

Replace with

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

Changing MaterialComponents to AppCompat works for me..

Answer (score 8):

Use this attribute `backgroundTint` it will help you. It work for me. Example :

```
android:backgroundTint="@color/md_orange_800"
```

Comment: This doesn't work well when using a drawable as background so changing to AppCompatButton is the better option so far as mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/a/66950268/8015914

Answer (score 6):

if you are using Android Studio Version 4.1 and above (Beta)
check your themes.xml file in values.

```
<style name="Theme.NavaFlashLightV4" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

change the attribute to @null

```
<style name="Theme.NavaFlashLightV4" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
            <!-- Primary brand color. -->
            <item name="colorPrimary">@null</item> <!-- HERE -->
            <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
            <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
    </style>
```

for other old versions of Android Studio

just change this attribute

```
<item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
```

to

```
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/@null</item>
```

finally set the background of the button to the drawable icon you want.
example:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSwitch"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" /> <!--the drawable you want-->
```

Comment: Setting the primary color to null causes the app to crash on Android Studio 4.2.

Comment: I think if you want to properly style your app and especially the buttons you need to stop using the MaterialComponents style as they replace the buttons with appCompat equivalents causing complexities.

Answer (score 6):

**You only need to change your App Theme from `Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar` to `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` inside styles.xml file**

example :

from : `style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar"`

To : `style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"`

Answer (score 0):

your style should be like this....

```
<style name="ButtonStlye123" >
    <item name="android:textSize">19dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_margin">8dp</item>
    <item name="android:padding">8dp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/ColorDivider</item>

    <item name="android:background">@color/ColorAccent</item>
</style>
```

and in layout

```
<Button
     android:id="@+id/btn3"
     style="@style/ButtonStlye123"
     android:layout_width="@dimen/sixzero"
     android:layout_height="@dimen/sixzero"
     android:text="3" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using targetSdk 30 and compileSdk 32 and I am using Button widget. Android Studio version 2021.1.1

In my case, following change worked,

In AndroidManifest.xml, under "application" tag changing "android:theme" from

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
```

to

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar"
```

I moved to Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar to remove the title bar. At first I tried to change "style" to "Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" inside themes.xml but it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

change background this:

```
<Button android:background="@color/black">
```

to this line >>>

```
<Button android:backgroundTint="@color/black">
```