# Styling theme buttons android (xml)

Tags: android, kotlin, user-interface, button, android-button

I'm having trouble with styling buttons in my app, I've tried using selectors, themes but none of that has worked for me (or worked but not as intended), any ideas what should I change to set it up correctly?

code:

one of buttons (the dark theme one (should swap colors from black to violet(when activated))

```
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/dark_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:theme="@style/buttonDark"
            android:text="dark"
            app:icon="@drawable/ic_moon"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

style:

```
    <style name="buttonDark" >
        <item name="android:state_active">@color/black</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:state_pressed">@color/violet</item>
    </style>
```

representation of the both light mode and dark mode (and the buttons in both):

[image]

Comment: Are you using a material components theme?

Comment: yes ("implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0-alpha02"")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a custom style:

```
    <Button
        style="@style/App.Button"
```

with:

```
<style name="App.Button" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button">
    <item name="backgroundTint">@color/mtrl_btn_bg_custom_selector</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/mtrl_btn_text_custom_color_selector</item>
    <item name="rippleColor">@color/mtrl_btn_custom_ripple_color</item>
</style>
```

The background tint selector define the background color:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/black" android:state_enabled="true"/>
    <item android:alpha="0.12" android:color="...."/> <!-- disabled -->
</selector>
```

The text color selector:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/white" android:state_enabled="true"/>
    <item android:alpha="0.38" android:color="...."/> <!-- disabled -->
</selector>
```

The ripple selector:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item  android:color="@color/violet500" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:color="@color/..." android:state_focused="true" android:state_hovered="true"/>
    <item android:color="@color/..." android:state_focused="true"/>
    <item  android:color="@color/..." android:state_hovered="true"/>
    <item  android:color="@color/..."/>
</selector>
```

Comment: I have no idea why, but It doesn't give any results either (even though I've added "theme" to one of the buttons and tweaked with the code you've provided)

Comment: @icecube It is a style. Apply it to a button using `style="@style/App.Button"`

Comment: yea, I've done that but it didn't work, however I might have found the solution here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31858374/android-button-background-color-not-changing) and I think I will be able to set it up

Comment: @icecube what is the issue? I've tried it and it works.

Comment: I've been using "Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar" instead of "Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" and the buttons did not change styles because of that

Comment: @icecube The answer is based on a material components theme.

Comment: I haven't really used that solution but it has led me to the correct solution so I will accept it