# Extended Spinner Color of DropDownSelector

Tags: android, colors, styles, themes, spinner

I want to set a color  to the DropDownSelector of a spinner. 
A "normal" Spinner class makes it's selector black, but an extended class makes it white.

The top one is the normal Spinner, bottom one is a custom spinner:
[image: The top one is the normal Spinner, bottom one is a custom spinner]

Both Spinners have `style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Spinner"` in the XML.

How do I make my Custom Spinner also use black as color for the selector?

Comment: This might be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28368354/child-class-of-edittext-looks-different-than-normal-edittext-on-android-4

Comment: Yes thanks, sounds similar. Do you know, how to tint the right background?